# Center navbar tabs for full size screens and within navbar-collapse for mobile screens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a `navbar` with several tabs on it. When the screen size becomes small enough these tabs disappear and collect in the form of a clickable button, `navbar-collapse`, which expands showing the tabs in a vertical manner. I was able to have the elements in the dropdown centered with `text-align: center`, but this does not seem to affect the tabs when the `navbar` is fullsize. Is there a way to center the tabs both on fullsize and mobile (on the dropdown) which I was already able to do. Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sushiknives/c1zjbrmj/

One note on the JSFiddle: you need to drag the result page far left to see what the page would look like full-size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `nav-justified`...

```
<ul class="nav nav-justified">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Condominii</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Chi Siamo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fornitori</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contatti</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dove Siamo</a></li>
</ul>
```

Demo: http://codeply.com/go/MSEeod5De9

Comment: I had tried before that but the tabs are shifted slightly towards the top of the navbar and I couldn't seem to fix that with CSS.